A non-copyrightable song is misrepresented as having copyright, and then distributed on subscription based services. What happens as a remedy?
A song is substantially generated using AI, but declared to be copyright by some entity, and then posted on music services such as Spotify, Apple Music, etc.
The copyright is then successfully challenged.
Since the song owner made revenue by using the implied threat of legal action to prevent free distribution, which was fraudulent, is it possible that each listener of the song should be given recourse and part of a money settlement?
If a popular artist was found to have created a song in this manner, would it predispose all of their songs to be without-copyright?  What would need to happen, in order to change the dynamic from, "needing to prove that it should not have copyright," to "needing to prove it should have copyright."

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

united-states
Nothing. Business goes on as usual.
Works without copyright can be commercialized / monetized without restriction. There's no damages created by its reasonable reproduction and/or use, therefore there's no actionable cause.
There's no damaged party. One example is Mickey Mouse. The character is in the public domain, thus without copyright, since Jan 1st, 2024. Disney still uses the character for profit, and won't stop doing so.
In the case of Carol Highsmith v Getty Images & Alamy, NY District Judge dismissed some of Highsmith's claims with prejudice. The remaining claims were settled sub rosa. [1]. The image services keep distributing (and profiting from) Highsmith's public domain images to this day.
A song is composed of several parts. Lyrics and Melody being the two main ones. A song (melody and synthsized instruments and vocals) can be generated by AI but based on Lyrics (let's call it a "poem") written by a human. Where does the song's copyright falls? Obviously, the parts created by AI don't have copyright attached, but the "poem" had its copyright created the moment the person wrote it. This was not tested in court but a reasonable person might believe that the lyrics are protected.
By using a streaming service or a music-distribution service, you agree to some terms. Spotify, for example (no endorsement is intended):

This Access shall remain in effect unless and until terminated by you or Spotify. You agree that you will not redistribute or transfer the Spotify Service or the Content.

And for Apple Music:

You may not use or export or re-export any Content or any copy or adaptation of such Content, or any product or service offered [...]

In both cases, there's no mention to copyright in the sections cited. You paid to access the content through their services and agreed to a contract.
You might find and listen to erudite music created by Bach, Mozart, and others in such streaming services. These compositions have no copyright, and yet you cannot redistribute the music sent to you by Spotify because of the T&S. You can get and then be free to redistribute the same erudite piece from another source, though. Whether the orchestra that performed the piece attaches copyright to that particular recording is beyond the scope of this answer.
Finally, each work is its own copyright(able) item. Just because one song by an artist might not have a copyright does not change the status of the other works.

Are you sure there are no damaged parties?  Because the owner knowingly lied in order to produce an outcome (forcing people to pay a service, which in turn pays them), which if they had not lied would not have happened.  There was some consequence (else they would not have lied), which seems to me, as if it is damage to those they lied to.

I actually have some music on CD that is completely out of copyright (performer is dead just over 70 years, composer even longer).

@iamacomputer, you keep using that term force...  Nobody is ever forced to buy a song.

You missed the important factor of performance copyright. Beethoven’s music is out of copyright, a recording of Beethoven performed by the London Symphony Orchestra in 1982 has copyright.

besides performance copyright, there's also the copyright in the remix/recording, separate from the music and texts...

The given examples (distributing public domain images etc.) feature one important distinction: the distributor is open about them not having copyright. Which means the buyers understand that they could possibly find them for free if they wanted to. Not so with the scenario in question. Thus, -1.

@DaleM didn't miss. quoting myself from the answer: "Whether the orchestra that performed the piece attaches copyright to that particular recording is beyond the scope of this answer." — now, is performing a score without any deviation transformative enough? that's for another question in this site.
